# Can the root user change the owner of a file that he doesn't own?

Tags: permissions, users, user-management, groups

My web server uses the user `www-data` to access/change files. This causes permission issues for php file upload etc. for files owned by `root` (or by any other user).

I'd like to use the 755/644 permissions for my folders/files (rather than 775/664), so I'd like to actually change the owner of the files to `www-data`, rather than just the group.

I don't want to run in to the situation where the `root` user can't access/modify the files though.

I'm sure this is basic knowledge for most people, but I just wanted to double-check it. If I change the owner:group of a file to `www-data:www-data`, will the `root` user still be able to edit/access the files? Would the `root` user be able to change it back to `root:root` if desired?

Comment: Fun experiment: do `chmod a-rwx` on a file. Then open it as root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most situations (read default installations), root can do anything a regular user can and much more. If you think root cannot do something, remember it can become a user who can :)

You'll be fine.